# Querying multiple models and putting results in a table

Tags: python, django

I've got these models:

```
class League(models.Model):
    ...

class Game(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, related_name='games')
    ...

class Competitor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='competitors')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='competitors')
    points = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ...
```

And I want to make a League-score-table in my template:

```
      | Game1 | Game2 | Game3 | Tot
Comp1 |       |       |   8   |  8
Comp2 |   5   |       |   1   |  6
Comp3 |       |   4   |   3   |  7
```

But I can't figure out how to make these kind of queries in the view. I get that I can get the Games of a League:

```
l = get_object_or_404(League, pk=id) 
g = l.games
```

And put it in the table header like this:

```
{% for game in g %}
<th>{{ game.name}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

But how do I get the list of distinct competitors for a League of games? Even if they have only played one game in the league.

And how to I iterate the competitors over the games to get the points? 
What methods should I look into here? Or is it a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do `game.competitors_set.all()` and get the competitors for a given game object. Maybe thats not exactly what you are looking for however. If you want to take a league object and get a query set that returns all the competitors in a league, I think what you want is:

```
league = League.objects.get(pk=<the league you want>)
competitors = Competitors.objects.filter(game__league=league)
```

~EDIT~

To do the iteration, you will want to collect the data in your view in some sort of dict in a format that makes sense for iteration, and then pass it to your template. One thing I did notice: You have "game" as a single instance for your competitor model. This implies that each competitor is only in a single game. I think you want to make that a ManyToManyField. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more info.

Comment: Yes that seems to work to get the competitors list! Thank you!

Comment: Yes but I still need some ideas on the second part. On how to do the actual iteration on each competitors points on each game and how to put the data in the tables. That was actually the harder part. :) But I'll try some more first and then accept your answer!